# Abour Ch-square, T and F distribution wrt of populationMean and Variance

Tags: statistics

State True or Fals
1. Difference of Population variance follows F distribution

2.Difference of Population Means, when Population variance are "known" follows Chi-Square

3.Difference of Population Means, when Population variance are "unknown" follows
T-Distribution

4. Population Mean, When Population Variance is known follows F distribution

Appreciate your response

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. false
2. false, follow z distribution
3. true
4. false, follow z distribution

Comment: thanks . can you pls state for 1st false, what is the actual distribution that it follows ?  is it chi-square

Comment: _Ratio_ of _sample_ variances follows F dist'n. _Population parameters_ are unknown fixed values, and so have no distributions. So either this is an incorrectly worded problem or a 'trick' problem. All are False--no distributions in any of the four.

Comment: makes sense Brunce ..cheers